# Multiplying a tuple by a scalar

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```
print(img.size)
print(10 * img.size)
```

This will print:

```
(70, 70)
(70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70)
```

I'd like it to print:

```
(700, 700)
```

Is there any way to do this without having to write:

```
print(10 * img.size[0], 10 * img.size[1])
```

PS: `img.size` is a PIL image. I don't know if that matters anything in this case.

Comment: What's wrong with `(10 * img.size[0], 10 * img.size[1])`?  I don't see why you need to overengineer something as simple as a multiplication of 2 integers.  Note that this tuple will always have only two elements!

Comment: I'm not overengineering. I am asking if there's a nicer, simpler way. Read my post again.

Comment: @paprika:  ...because the tuple in question may not have a known length.  In this case it does (as it did in the case that led me to this question), but coding for an assumed tuple length, repeating the scalar *n* times, and having to get *n* indexes right is kludgy enough to avoid if straightforwardly possible.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Might be a nicer way, but this should work

```
tuple([10*x for x in img.size])
```

Comment: Slightly nicer: `tuple(10*x for x in img.size)`

Answer (score 53):

```
img.size = tuple(i * 10 for i in img.size)
```

Answer (score 18):

The **pythonic** way would be using a list comprehension:

```
y = tuple([z * 10 for z in img.size])
```

Another way could be:

```
y = tuple(map((10).__mul__, img.size))
```

Comment: That second one is awesome... haha.

Comment: Neither example captures the point of the question. Both force the programmer to take a simple idea (scalar times matrix multiplication) and deconstruct it.

Comment: @ZekeHansell What's wrong with "forcing" the programmer to deconstruct his idea? Deconstructing a problem down in order to encapsulate the solution with code is the essence of programming. All of the above answers solve the issue that the asker was asking, in ways that approach the problem at its core, and solve it in repeatable, re-usable bits of code (all one-liners BTW). The code can be easily expanded to accept any arbitrary constant to perform simple scalar-vector multiplication, and the asker has gained a new approach, as well as a new tool in his/her belt.

So where's the issue?

Comment: You are correct in your analysis/criticism of my comment. Maybe I have grown wiser in the years since my original comment.
I've certainly learned something from you. @Isaac

Answer (score 11):

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
set1=(70, 70)
tuple(2*np.array(set1))
```

Explanation: `arrays` make direct scalar multiplication possible. Hence the `tuple` called `set1` here is converted to an `array`. I assume you wish to keep using the `tuple`, hence we convert the `array` back to a `tuple`.

This solution is to avoid the explicit and verbose `for` loop. I do not know whether it is faster or whether the exact same thing happens in both cases.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 2 or 3, as far as I can tell.  I assume `array` comes from the `array` module?  Python expects a character as the first argument to `array`, thus passing only a tuple in will fail with `TypeError: array() argument 1 or typecode must be char (string or ascii-unicode with length 1), not tuple`.  Can you expand on this with a more complete example?

Comment: I assume it is a numpy array?

Comment: It's a numpy array, which is why its import is the first line. It's expected that any non-standard array manipulations are done with numpy.

Answer (score 7):

Simplish thing if you're writing a bunch of code, but don't want a more complicated vector library...

```
class V(tuple):
    '''A simple vector supporting scalar multiply and vector add'''
    def __new__ (cls, *args):
        return super(V, cls).__new__(cls, args)
    def __mul__(self,s):
        return V( *( c*s for c in self) )
    def __add__(self,s):
        return V( *( c[0]+c[1] for c in zip(self,s)) )
    def __repr__(self):
        return "V" + super(V, self).__repr__()

# As long as the "vector" is on the left it just works

xaxis = V(1.0, 0.0)
yaxis = V(0.0, 1.0)
print xaxis + yaxis      # => V(1.0, 1.0)
print xaxis*3 + yaxis*5  # => V(3.0, 5.0)
print 3*xaxis            # Broke, => (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

The "V" instances otherwise behave just like tuples.  This requires that the "V" instances are all created with the same number of elements.  You could add, for example, to __new__

```
if len(args)!=2: raise TypeError('Must be 2 elements')
```

to enforce that all the instances are 2d vectors....

Answer (score 5):

There is probably a simpler way than this, but

```
print map(lambda x: 10*x, img.size)
```

Will do nearly what you want, although it prints as a list rather than a tuple. Wrap the `map` call inside `tuple(map...)` if you want it to print as a tuple (parentheses rather than square brackets).

Comment: The lambda function can be replaced by 'map((10).__mul__, img.size)'

Answer (score 4):

If you have this problem more often and with larger tuples or lists then you might want to use the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) library, which allows you to do all kinds of mathematical operations on arrays. However, in this simple situation this would be complete overkill.

Comment: While for the *simple* example would be overkill to use numpy, the point of the question seems to be "Does python offer a way mimic operations can be simply expressed in math?" I mean if you have a matrix A = [ 70 70 ] then 2A = [ 140 140 ].

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
print [10 * s for s in img.size]
```

It will give you a new list with all the elements you have in the tuple multiplied by 10

Answer (score 3):

In line with the previous answers but using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
result = tuple(10*np.array(img.size))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply the function on Tuple as a whole.
You need to apply it on individual elements and return a new tuple.

```
newTuple = tuple([10*x for x in oldTuple])
```

Remember you cannot change a Tuple.

Answer (score 2):

**Just to overview**

```py
import timeit

# tuple element wise operations multiplication

# native
map_lambda = """
a = tuple(range(10000))
b = tuple(map(lambda x: x * 2, a))
"""

# native
tuple_comprehension = """
a = tuple(range(10000))
b = tuple(x * 2 for x in a)
"""

# numpy
using_numpy = """
import numpy as np
a = tuple(range(10000))
b = tuple((np.array(a) * 2).tolist())
"""

print('map_lambda =', timeit.timeit(map_lambda, number=1000))
print('tuple_comprehension =', timeit.timeit(tuple_comprehension, number=1000))
print('using_numpy =', timeit.timeit(using_numpy, number=1000))
```

**Timings on my machine**

```py
map_lambda = 1.541315148000649
tuple_comprehension = 1.0838452139996662
using_numpy = 1.2488984129995515
```

Answer (score 1):

adding nothing but variety [edit: and inefficiency<s>, and error</s>]..

```
img_size = (70, 70)
tuple(map(__import__('operator').mul, img_size, len(img_size)*(10,)))
```

[edit: fixed wrong return type, munged operator use, left the inefficient multiplier generation!]