# How can I divide each element in a tuple by a single integer?

Tags: python

I want to divide a tuple by an integer. I am expecting something like this:

```
tuple = (10,20,30,50,80)
output = tuple/10
print(output)
output = (1,2,3,5,8)
```

Comment: a Thermal conductivity simulator

Comment: pedram.py: This has already been asked and answered. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244949/914547

Comment: Another similar asked and answered post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781970/multiplying-a-tuple-by-a-scalar

Comment: i want to tuple not list

Comment: @pedram.py Then see the link I posted above. The answer gives a tuple.

Comment: i try this but it dont worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you could try if it is a numbers tuple:

```
numberstuple = (5,1,7,9,6,3)
divisor = 2.0
divisornodecimals = 2

value = map(lambda x: x/divisor, numberstuple)
>>>[2.5, 0.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 1.5]
valuewithout_decimals = map(lambda x: x/divisornodecimals, numberstuple)
>>>[2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1]
```

or

```
value = [x/divisor for x in numberstuple]
```

Comment: very thanks sir it has been worked!

Comment: I'm happy to help, I recommend you learn about List Comprehensions

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1782003/2680824) by Truppo (and shown below) is much easier to work with and remember

Comment: Not sure how this is the accepted answer, when they asked for the output to be tuple. The output here is list. The answer by @BenLindsay posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386830/6260862) is the same but with the correct output type, so it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782003/2680824) by Truppo.

```
>>> t = (10,20,30)
>>> t2 = tuple(ti/2 for ti in t)
>>> t2
(5, 10, 15)
```